# What is the sphericity and roundness of Saône River Sand

Tags: sedimentology, rivers

I'm interested in knowing about [Saône River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%C3%B4ne) sand found at the river's headwater just outside the city of Dijon, France, as seen in the image below, Saône highlighted red, Dijon highlighted yellow. (This would be the sand found along the riverbank).

[image]

Referring to the figure below, what is known (or thought) about the sphericity and roundness of the Saône sand near Dijon? I.e., what value for sphericity (y-axis) and roundness (x-axis) characterizes the sand?

[image]

Can anyone provide a picture of the sand?

Comment: Seems rather a specialized request rather than a broad use question (unless someone has a wider resource??), so think there's a chance the question gets closed as [not relevant to others](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or at least little input?  You might instead consider making requests on like Twitter or Facebook tagged to groups/cities in the area if you are motivated to success???